# Why is my question on testing nested dictionaries in Python too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question I asked recently today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961523/how-to-test-if-key-is-in-dictionary-inside-another-dictionary) has been put "on hold" for being too broad when all I needed was a simple one-line answer. Someone in the comments even answered the whole question in one line.

I don't understand why it has gotten so many downvotes and now has been closed. Does anyone care to shed some light? Maybe the people who voted to close it and didn't bother to explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea. Your edit helped (showing your work is always nice), but even without that you provided a reasonably clear example of what you were trying to do right at the start.

I've reopened the question.